# MS Access database clears all data every time after press "Re-Build Solution" in 'Build' menu in the application

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I have read the old solution given to change the property of database .accdb `copy to output dictionary`. Already done that and after this problem arise.Data inserted properly in database.
After closing the application and re-run the application, the inserted data is showing in database as well as in gridView. But after re-build the application the data is lost.

```
    private OleDbConnection conn;
    private OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    private String connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Data.accdb";
    private String query;       

    public workers()
    {
        conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;  

        query = "INSERT into workers(`w_name`,`w_salary`,`w_daysal`,`w_credit`,`w_leave`,`w_remain`) values(@w_name,@w_salary,@w_daysal,@w_credit,@w_leave,@w_remain);";

            cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@w_name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = nameTxt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@w_salary", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = salaryTxt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@w_daysal", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = creditTxt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@w_credit", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = daysalTxt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@w_leave", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = leaveTxt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@w_remain", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = remainTxt.Text;

       try
       {
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           MessageBox.Show("Data Added");
           BindGrid();

           clearData();
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);
        }
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {            
        conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM workers";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "table");            

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "table";
        dataGridView1.Update();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();

        nameTxt.Focus(); 
    }
```

Comment: waht is clearData();?  access sql doesn't support ` for entity name replace ` with [

Comment: Thank you for the response. 'clearData()' is just a function to clear text boxes after adding the values. As u suggest I have replaced all entity with square brackets [ ] but I am getting the same result. @krishKM

Comment: I would try moving conn = new OleDbConnection(connString); to the click event.  Add  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; too.

Comment: if the data is appearing and disappearing in MS access db, either you are using trasactions or inserting and deleting. find out what you are doing and use the "using" method and let the system close the connection once you are done with operations.

Comment: This is a common problem when running your application from Visual Studio.

Comment: @Andre yes it has that problem and that is why we are here to help each other and solve it together.

Comment: @SQLDBA i tried both the suggestions..but in the end the result is the same. i have used `conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);`  in the constructor. so it is not required in both places.

Comment: Also try simplifying.  So comment out params and just do this:  query = "INSERT into workers('w_name','w_salary','w_daysal','w_credit','w_leave','w_remain') values('a','b','c,','d','e','f');";  (remove quotes if int)